# Editar un archivo de texto o html desde bat

Tags: javascript, html

He hecho una variable donde se el usuario introduce un nombre y se guarda en esa variable:

```
@echo off

echo Introduce el CID de tu RIF: 
set /p cid=

PAUSE>Nul
```

Ahora lo que necesito es que lo que el usuario introduzca en esa variable se escriba en un archivo .js

Comment: Hola Klaim, ¿Podrías poner un código con lo que has intentado? nos ayudaría bastante a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Esque no lo he intentado porque no se me ocurre como hacerlo, lo que necesito es como hacerlo xDDDD, no se me ocurre como

Comment: Para que tus preguntas tengan mejor recepción, te recomiendo hacer el tour: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y leerte el cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Aquí ayudamos con problemas concretos, pero eso que pides tiene muchas formas de hacerse, te animo a que investigues un poco por internet y las dudas puntuales las preguntes aquí. ¡Ánimo!

Comment: ya lo he editado mejor jeje

Comment: bueno, algo es algo, aunque debes mejorar la pregunta donde detalles el problema, porque para escribir un valor en un fichero con bash, te sirve este comando `valor > fichero` siendo valor, la variable y fichero el nombre del fichero. Pero  entiendo que tú no quieres eso.

Comment: El problema de eso es que sobreescribe todo y solo pone lo de la variable, necesito que reemplaze una linea de un .js solamente

Comment: Lo se, lo más fácil va a ser leer línea a línea el fichero con bash y cuando encuentres lo que quieres, cambias el valor